# Does copying/moving data between variables consumes less cycles per byte than adding/rotating/xoring?

Tags: performance

A round of [Salsa20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20) is done as follows:

```
b ^= (a + d) <<< 7;
c ^= (b + a) <<< 9;
d ^= (c + b) <<< 13;
a ^= (d + c) <<< 18;
```

The Salsa20 variant called ChaCha20 has its round function like this:

```
 a += b; d ^= a; d <<<= 16;
 c += d; b ^= c; b <<<= 12;
 a += b; d ^= a; d <<<= 8;
 c += d; b ^= c; b <<<= 7;
```

ChaCha20 has 8 more word copies than Salsa20. The [optimized version of Salsa has 3.91 cpb on an Intel Core 2 Duo](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle.html#speed) and [ChaCha20 has 3.95 cpb on the same processor](https://cr.yp.to/chacha/chacha-20080128.pdf).

Both two ciphers has similar performances despite ChaCha20 having more copying operation between variables.

My question is:

Does copying/moving data between variables consumes less cycles per byte than adding/rotating/xoring?

PS: I know that this question is related to programming and maybe should be asked in the Stack Overflow, but I'm just showing Salsa20/ChaCha20 as references. My questions is about the performance different between copying/moving operations and other common operations performed by the processor.

Comment: The Salsa20 and ChaCha round functions are a bad example, because they can both be implemented without any register copy/move instructions on common CPUs. The variable assignments in the C code have nothing to do with the generated machine code (unless you compile without optimization).